# My script runs in powershell ISE but not powershell console?

Tags: powershell

```
function Get-LoggedOnUsers ($server) {

if($server -eq $null){
    $server = "localhost"
}

$users = @()
# Query using quser, 2>$null to hide "No users exists...", then skip to the next server
$quser = quser /server:$server 2>$null
if(!($quser)){
    Continue
}

#Remove column headers
$quser = $quser[1..$($quser.Count)]
foreach($user in $quser){
    $usersObj = [PSCustomObject]@{Server=$null;Username=$null;SessionName=$null;SessionId=$Null;SessionState=$null;LogonTime=$null;IdleTime=$null}
    $quserData = $user -split "\s+"

    #We have to splice the array if the session is disconnected (as the SESSIONNAME column quserData[2] is empty)
    if(($user | select-string "Disc") -ne $null){
        #User is disconnected
        $quserData = ($quserData[0..1],"null",$quserData[2..($quserData.Length -1)]) -split "\s+"
    }

    # Server
    $usersObj.Server = $server
    # Username
    $usersObj.Username = $quserData[1]
    # SessionName
    $usersObj.SessionName = $quserData[2]
    # SessionID
    $usersObj.SessionID = $quserData[3]
    # SessionState
    $usersObj.SessionState = $quserData[4]
    # IdleTime
    $quserData[5] = $quserData[5] -replace "\+",":" -replace "\.","0:0" -replace "Disc","0:0"
    if($quserData[5] -like "*:*"){
        $usersObj.IdleTime = [timespan]"$($quserData[5])"
    }elseif($quserData[5] -eq "." -or $quserData[5] -eq "none"){
        $usersObj.idleTime = [timespan]"0:0"
    }else{
        $usersObj.IdleTime = [timespan]"0:$($quserData[5])"
    }
    # LogonTime
    $usersObj.LogonTime = (Get-Date "$($quserData[6]) $($quserData[7]) $($quserData[8] )")

    $users += $usersObj


}

return $users
  }

function LogOutUser {
    $test = Get-LoggedOnUsers
    $count = 0
    $nameArray = @()
    $sessionArray = @()
    $logonTimeArray = @()
    foreach($line in $test){
        $field1 = $line.Username
        $field2 = $line.SessionID
        $field3 = $line.LogonTime
        $nameArray += $field1
        $sessionArray += $field2
        $logonTimeArray += $field3
        $count+=1
    }
    $session1 = [INT]$sessionArray[0]
    $session2 = [INT]$sessionArray[1]
    Write-Host $nameArray
    Write-Host $sessionArray
    Write-Host $logonTimeArray
    Write-Host $count
    Write-Host $session1
    Write-Host $session2


    if(($count -gt 1) -and ($session2 -gt $session1 )){
        logoff $session1

    }

}


Get-LoggedOnUsers
LogOutUser
```

this code works in the ISE but it does not work when running from the console, what is happening? It does exactly what i want it to do through the ISE but when I try running as a scheduled task it doesn't work also it doesnt work when trying to run with console. i have tried powershell.exe -noexit -file c:\logofftest1.ps1 but still no success

Comment: What's the error message you are getting? You need to post it too. Saying _it doesn't work_ simply isn't enough.

Comment: runs with no errors but doesn't do anything

Comment: You can't conclude that it's not doing anything. You need to run it to log verbosely what it is doing.

Comment: If it's hard to figure out the issue while you have full control of it, it will be impossible for the community to find the issue.

Comment: what do you mean? you could copy and paste the script and it should run for you if you are an administrator there is nothing specific to my machine

Comment: how do i run with verbose?

Comment: it does not print out the write host statement. but when run in the ISE it runs perfectly and i have restarted my machine and run from the ISE again

Comment: http://windowsitpro.com/blog/verbose-and-debug-output-powershell and https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/heyscriptingguy/2014/07/30/use-powershell-to-write-verbose-output/ might help.

Comment: when i copy and paste the code directly to the console it works?

Comment: When running as a task, you don't have access to console. Try `-PSConsoleFile <FilePath>` and see if `Write-Host` ends outputting there.

Comment: when I copy and paste it to the console it shows my user details as output (I edited it so it won't log me off). And when I save it in a .ps1 and run it from the PowerShell console, it shows output. And when I save it and run it from a command prompt with `powershell -noexit -file test.ps1` it shows output as well.

Comment: hmm must be something about my user settings then

Comment: Try `powershell -NoProfile -file ...`

Comment: i got it to work by just copying and pasting the contents into a new ps1 file dont know what was happening with the older one