# Sublime Text causing PowerShell script to fail

Tags: powershell, sublimetext3

I have been using SublimeText for a while now and haven't had any issues until recently. Every now and again if I write a PowerShell script in sublime text, the script will fail to run with generic errors such as:

```
Missing closing '}' in statement block or type definition.
At C:\Users\user\OneDrive\Scripts\~Projects\TRIS-AzureMigration\TRIS-AzureMigration.ps1:7 char:25
+ function Get-SQLInstall {
```

These errors only show if I call the script from PowerShell. If I copy the script to the console it works. If I run it in ISE it works. I can also run it if I copy the code to notepad and then save it as a .ps1 from there, this tells me that it is something to do with sublime text.

I have had a look around and found a few examples:

[My script runs in powershell ISE but not powershell console?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40273696/my-script-runs-in-powershell-ise-but-not-powershell-console)   :: solution was to copy to a new file, which i dont want to have to do every time.

Any help  on this would be much appreciated.

The code block of code that for the error above:

```
function Get-SQLInstall {
    param ( [parameter(Mandatory=$false)]$GetMax = $true)

    $instances = @();
    $inst = (get-itemproperty 'HKLM:\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Microsoft SQL Server').InstalledInstances;


    foreach ($i in $inst)
    {
        $p = (Get-ItemProperty 'HKLM:\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Microsoft SQL Server\Instance Names\SQL').$i;
        [version]$v = ((Get-ItemProperty "HKLM:\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Microsoft SQL Server\$p\Setup").Edition).Major;

        $instances += New-Object –TypeName PSObject -Property @{
            Edition = ((Get-ItemProperty "HKLM:\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Microsoft SQL Server\$p\Setup").Edition);
            version = (Get-ItemProperty "HKLM:\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Microsoft SQL Server\$p\Setup").Version;
            SQLPath = (Get-ItemProperty "HKLM:\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Microsoft SQL Server\$p\Setup").SqlPath;
            SQLFullPath = ((Get-ItemProperty "HKLM:\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Microsoft SQL Server\$p\Setup").SqlPath) + "\" + [string]$v.major + "0";
        }
    }

    if ($GetMax -eq $true) {
        ## Get latest SQL version
        $max = ($instances | measure-object -Property version -maximum).maximum;
        return @($instances | ? { $_.version -eq $max})[0];
    }
    else {
        return $instances;
    }
}
```

Comment: Fix your character encoding? I bet you're saving as an encoding PS cannot read.  You need ASCII or UCS 16 LE with BOM. Maybe UTF8 with BOM. But definitely not UTF8 without BOM. And quite possibly stop using smartquotes, but it's difficult to troubleshoot your script when you haven't included your script (*hint hint*)

Comment: Thanks for this, i believe it defaults to UTF but i can save as UTF 16 LE  with BOM. Ill give that a go.

Comment: The errors are never correct which is why i didnt feel the need to include the script.

Comment: Errors can't really be wrong from the parser's perspective; if it can't see a `}` then there's something leading it astray before that. And if that's invisible to a human eye, it's likely some other odd byte(s) in the file - whitespace, line endings, character encodings. I don't know what would cause that specific error though, and can't quickly find something that does it which doesn't also look broken.

Comment: Yeah, they were all missing character errors i.e. { or ending " and were on different lines every time I ran it. Your fix seems to have resolved the issue so thank you.